# Angular loads children components before *ngIf condition runs and then hides them

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one component that is being used for authorization. If a user is not authorized they won't be able to see specific elements. I have some HTTP calls to the particular elements. Like get projects.

Let me give you an example here:

***app.component.ts***

```
<authorized>
   <app-project></app-project>
</authorized>
```

The authorize component is suppose to protect app-project to be loaded because I have *ngIf in the authorize.component.ts.

***authorize.component.ts***:

```
<ng-template #authorized *ngIf="isAuthorized">
  <ng-content></ng-content> <<--- app-project
</ng-template>
```

Is there a way to prevent the app-project to be loaded before isAuthorized condition is executed?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  template: `
    <div>I'm not visible</div>`
})
export class ProjectComponent {
  constructor() {
    alert(`This message shouldn't be called`);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authorize',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="false">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AuthorizeComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `
    <app-authorize>
      <app-project></app-project>
    </app-authorize>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should turn the `isAuthorized` into a Subject and use the `async` pipe instead. This makes sure that rendering will only happen when you are sure (the response comes back from the server) that the component should indeed render or not.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu it didn't solve the problem ☹️

Comment: You tried it that fast? :) Keep working on it, this should be the way. What kind of subject did you use? Use a plain `Subject` and just `next` when the response from the server comes.

Comment: I just put the false in the *ngIf but the <app-project> is still loading.

Comment: Do you initialize `isAuthorized` to anything? Also, `ngIf` creates a `ng-template` so you might be doubling up the elements and should put the `ngIf` on a different element.

Comment: @MatthewGreen even if I put false instead of isAuthorize it doesn't work.

Comment: Bear in mind that when you use ng-content in this way, the parent of the component being inserted in is the one you write it in as far as angular change detection is concerned, not the one with ng-content in. This could go some way to explaining why it is being constructed and then hidden, and why the behaviour persists with false in the *ngIf - it could be waiting for another change detection cycle to apply the ngIf to the content. I'm really uncertain tho...

Comment: I agree with @OctavianMărculescu, but with a little twist: I would use a BehaviorSubject (instead of the Subject) instantiated with a false initial value (so that by default the user is assumed to be not authenticated in the beginning). Then, when you get the response of the authentication call, if successful you emit a `true` from this BehaviourSubject to which you subscribe in the authorize component using a async pipe. Even better, you should subscribe in the authorize component to a Observable derived from the BehaviorSubject using .asObservable (it's considered a good practice)